# how to call a member function in python by its function instance？

Tags: python

Suppose we have the following code:

```
class T(object):
  def m1(self, a):
    ...
f=T.m1
```

How to call f on an instance of T?

```
x=T()
x.f(..)?
f(x, ..)?
```

Answer (score 3):

A member function is just like any other function, except it takes `self` as the first argument and there is a mechanism which passes that argument automatically.

So, the short answer is, use it ths way:

```
class T(object):
  def m1(self, a):
    pass

f=T.m1

x = T()

f(x, 1234)
```

### Unbound Method

This is because you are using T.m1, which is an *"unbound method"*. Unbound here means that its `self` argument is not bound to an instance.

```
>>> T.m1
<unbound method T.m1>
```

### Bound Method

Unlike `T.m1`, `x.m1` gives you a bound method:

```
>>> x.m1
<bound method T.m1 of <__main__.T object at 0x0000000002483080>>
```

You can reference a bound method and use it without passing `self` explicitly:

```
f2 = x.m1
f2(1234)
```

### Bind using `partial`

You can also do the equivalent "binding" `self` yourself, with this code:

```
import functools

unbound_f = T.m1
bound_f = functools.partial(unbound_f, x)

bound_f(1234)
```

Comment: You can also use the `@staticmethod` decorator

Comment: @RafazZ If you used `@staticmethod` you would have different behaviour. The function would not have a `self` argument. Here, `m1` receives a `self` in each of the three cases I wrote. If `self` is not used within `m1`, then yes - `@staticmethod` would be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this explains it!

```
class T(object):
    def m1(self, a):
        return a
f=T().m1 #must initialize the class using '()' before calling a method of that class
f(1)

f = T()
f.m1(1)

f = T().m1(1)

f = T
f().m1(1)

f = T.m1
f(T(), 1) #can call the method without first initializing the class because we pass a reference of the methods class

f = T.m1
f2 = T()
f(f2, 1)
```